# Inserting dynamic method in controller in laravel

Tags: laravel, controller

I need to insert in my user controller method dynamically
because I have every user has role and every role have some permissions 
and admin of my site can change permissions of any role insert new permission or delete one.

How can handing permissions functions dynamically 
in my user controller?

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Comment: @shoieb0101 know it and how to use it , but i need to know how to handle adding dynamic function to the controller because i do not need if the user do not have any permission not to include this permission function in user controller for example if user now to ability to add new user to the system and tomorrow i will delete this permission from  db but how to delete this function from controller while there is a way to make a middleware to this permission url but i don`t need just this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Laravel's Policies, specifically the controller helper ones.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#via-controller-helpers